# Apache, Nginx, and static content

Tags: apache, nginx, static-content

There seems to be a consensus that Nginx serves *static* content faster than Apache. However, I'm not really sure what this means. For example, I have a script that generates an image *only* if the same image doesn't already exist in the cache. If it does exist in the cache, the script simply returns the public address of the image.

Would this be considered dynamic, static, or both? More importantly, would Nginx still have a speed advantage with this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of web servers, "static" usually means the content is already known to exist in a file on disk and is not generated dynamically by running a program of any kind.

It sounds like your script, since it's a script, is *dynamic* content.

Comment: That makes sense. So I wonder if there would be any benefit to switching to Nginx. I guess I'll just need to try it and see...

Comment: Yes, trying and measuring is the only reliable way to know for sure, since there are so many different factors that can ultimately affect performance.